# Launch pycharm from cmd in windows

Tags: python, pycharm, command-line-interface

I can't be able to launch pycham (community version) from the cmd. I also set up the environment variable but still, I am getting this- 'pycharm-community' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I have used all these commands - `charm`, `charm.`, `pycharm.`, `pycharm`. But, I am getting the same problem.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html refer to this

Comment: yes, I already go through this and used that toolbox app but still command is not recognized.

Comment: Have you tried restarting you computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MS windows:

1. Find where your pycharm is installed
2. If it is installed in C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\

Type this in cmd:

```
setx PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\bin
```

if not, then replace the path to where you pycharm is installed

```
setx PATH=%PATH%;C:\Path\to\your\pycharm\bin
```

If this doesn't work, try to restart you system once.

To start pycharm using command, first see what is the file name for executable for pycharm inside the bin folder and use that name. It can be pycharm.exe or something similar.

If it is pycharm.exe, use 'pycharm' in cmd to start it.

Comment: here its my path-"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\bin\pycharm64.exe"

Comment: type this in cmd:    setx PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\bin\

Comment: To start pycharm use 'pycharm64' in cmd